# How to load dump file in neo4j running inside docker?

Tags: windows, docker, neo4j

I tried a couple of things but none seem to have worked.

I used the following command to copy the dump file into the container.

```
docker cp ./db.dump a2198b1e36e5:/var/lib/neo4j/import/db.dump
```

And then I used the following to load it into the db.

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \ 
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/backups:/backups \ 
    neo4j/neo4j-admin:4.4.9 \
neo4j-admin load --database=neo4j --from=/var/lib/neo4j/import/db.dump
```

But it threw and exception that the database must be stopped before loading the dump file.

Interestingly enough I can't stop the database because it's not enterprise version.

`STOP DATABASE neo4j;` // fails with error "Unsupported administrative command.."

Comment: @jose_bacoy how can I do that?

Comment: You can only stop/create/stop database using enterprise edition. https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/databases/#administration-databases-stop-database

Comment: @jose_bacoy so in short there is no way to import dump file inside neo4j running on docker on my local machine?

Comment: You can shutdown your database then do an offline load (restore).

Comment: @jose_bacoy when I shut down the database.. it also shuts down the container

Answer (score 1):

For the community version the easiest way I found of doing this is to restore a database with a name other than neo4j.

```
neo4j-admin load --database=dumpdatabase--from=/var/lib/neo4j/import/db.dump
```

Then you stop the docker container, and run it with the default database env variable.

```
docker run --interactive --tty --rm \
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/data:/data \ 
    --volume=$HOME/neo4j/backups:/backups \ 
    --env NEO4J_default__database=dumpdatabase \
    neo4j/neo4j-admin:4.4.9
```

I should note that you should persist the data folder for this solution, which you already do.